# Publishing on arXiv effect online scholarly profile

Tags: publications, arxiv, online-publication

This question is closely related to this: 
[Options to publish a paper "as is" without being able to produce "more results"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14796/options-to-publish-a-paper-as-is-without-being-able-to-produce-more-results)

I'm curious if posting on arXiv adds to your online scholarly profile, such ason Google or CiteSeerX. I know some arXiv papers indexed by Google scholar that have quite a few citations in good peer-reviewed journals directly, but conversely I can't find an example of an arXiv paper in the publication list of any author on their scholarly profile (though I have found the subsequent peer-reviewed versions listed).

Are arXiv papers somehow excluded on such profiles? Do they not affect you h-index on such sites?

This seems relevant if you don't want a low tier publication on your CV but do want your results to be out there and visible for someone viewing your track record.

Comment: _I can't find an example of an arXiv paper in the publication list of any author on their scholarly profile_ — I don't know what you mean by "scholarly profile".  If you mean "CV", then examples are easy—visit almost any mathematician's personal web page; for example, [Terry Tao](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/honeycombs.html).  If you mean "Web of Science" or some other similar commercial service, then of course not; what incentive would a journal publisher have to admit that preprints exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both Google Scholar and CiteSeerX can detect arXiv publications.  I know for certain on Google Scholar because it has detected mine (and it is also adding to my H-index on the site).  For CiteSeerX, if you search by publication venue, you will find many publications in arXiv.  Both systems will, however, attempt to merge versions (and Google Scholar at least allows a person to do this manually as well), so a subsequent journal publication can supersede the arXiv version, making such an arXiv version apparently invisible even if it is part of the profile and collecting citations.

Neither system makes any guarantees, however, about how *quickly* it will detect papers in particular venues, so it is possible that arXiv is updated less frequently or more erratically than others (particularly for CiteSeerX, which is often plagued by maintenance issues).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes. Google scholar and even DBLP (for computer science) do record arxiv publication. Though they might treat them as "informal" publications. As far as I checked it is also counted in your citation counts.

Comment: Nice, I did know *of* DBLP having used it sometmes to look up articles, but I always sort of assumed that people with profiles on DBLP were at some time employees of Uni Trier (which was odd on its own, never heard of that particular university being a hub of computer science advancements).